# Inserting ListBox Items to .accdb with C#

Tags: c#, database, listbox

I'm confused any help would be great.

I have a listbox with employee names that are read in from a .accdb. That part works fine. Then I make changes to the listbox items in the windowsform. Now I want to insert the changes I've made in the listbox back to the .accdb. My problem is when I click the save button it is only adding the first item in my listbox instead of each one. I'm not sure why it's only adding the one item instead of them all. Thanks a lot if you can help!

```
    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=WorkReportDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

        OleDbConnection connectEmployee = new OleDbConnection();
        connectEmployee.ConnectionString = connectString;
        connectEmployee.Open();

        OleDbCommand commandEmployee = new OleDbCommand();
        commandEmployee.Connection = connectEmployee;
        commandEmployee.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable (TestColumn) VALUES (@TestTable)";

        for(int i = 0; i < EmployeeList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string item = EmployeeList.GetItemText(EmployeeList.Items[i]);

            commandEmployee.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestTable", item);

            commandEmployee.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        connectEmployee.Close();           
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing out the parameters since you keep adding them:

```
commandEmployee.Parameters.Clear();
commandEmployee.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestTable", item);
```